# Validate xml document against DTD

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have generated the xml document using `XDocument` and create a `Document type declaration (DTD)`.

But i could not validate the DTD against the generated `XML`.

What is the best way to check whether the DTD is properly created or not?

Is there any way in `c#` to dynamically generate the DTD?

I have explicitly created a `InternalSubset` in my code, what is the purpose of adding the name `bookstoredoc.dtd` in the line below in `XDocumentType` decleration?

```
XDocumentType docType = new XDocumentType("bookstoredoc", null,
    "bookstoredoc.dtd",
    @"<!ELEMENT bookstore (book+)>
    <!ELEMENT book (title|year|price|author+) >
    <!ATTLIST book
        category CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST title
      lang CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT author (name+)>
    <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>");
```

Code:

```
var bookObj = new BookStore();
var bookList = bookObj.GetBookStores();
XDocumentType docType = new XDocumentType("bookstoredoc", null,
    "bookstoredoc.dtd",
    @"<!ELEMENT bookstore (book+)>
    <!ELEMENT book (title|year|price|author+) >
    <!ATTLIST book
        category CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST title
      lang CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ELEMENT year (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT author (name+)>
    <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>");

var xmlDocument = new XDocument(docType, new XElement("bookstore",
    bookList.Select(x =>
        new XElement("book", new XAttribute("Name", x.Category),
        new XElement("title", new XAttribute("lang", x.Lang), x.Title),
        new XElement("year", x.Year),
        new XElement("price", x.Price),
        new XElement("author", x.Author.Select(y => new XElement("name", y.Name)))
   ))));



xmlDocument.Save(@"D:\Test.xml");
```

BookStore.cs

```
public class BookStore
{
    public BookCategory Category { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Author> Author { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public string Lang { get; set; }
    public List<BookStore> GetBookStores()
    {
        var list = new List<BookStore>()
        {
            new BookStore
            {
                Category = BookCategory.COOKING,
                Title = "Everyday Italian",
                Author = new List<Author>()
                {
                    new Author{ Name = "Giada De Laurentiis"}
                },
                Year = 2005,
                Price = 30.00,
                Lang = "en"
            }, new BookStore
            {
                Category = BookCategory.CHILDREN,
                Title = "Harry Potter",
                Author = new List<Author>()
                {
                    new Author{ Name = "J K. Rowling"}
                },
                Year = 2005,
                Price = 29.99,
                Lang = "en"
            },new BookStore
            {
                Category = BookCategory.WEB,
                Title = "XQuery Kick Start",
                Author = new List<Author>()
                {
                    new Author{ Name = "James McGovern"},
                    new Author{ Name = "Per Bothner"},
                    new Author{ Name = "Kurt Cagle"},
                    new Author{ Name = "James Linn"},
                    new Author{ Name = "Vaidyanathan Nagarajan"},
                },
                Year = 2003,
                Price = 49.99,
                Lang = "en"
            },new BookStore
            {
                Category = BookCategory.WEB,
                Title = "Learning XML",
                Author = new List<Author>()
                {
                    new Author{ Name = "Erik T. Ray"}
                },
                Year = 2003,
                Price = 39.95,
                Lang = "en"
            }

        };

        return list;
    }
}
public enum BookCategory
{
    COOKING,
    CHILDREN,
    WEB
}
public class Author
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```